# Android Face detection Library

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using face detection for building an application. I cannot figure out what library must I import to support **Face []** (face Array parameter) in the following code:

```
class MyFaceDetectionListener implements Camera.FaceDetectionListener {

@Override
public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
    if (faces.length > 0){
        Log.d("FaceDetection", "face detected: "+ faces.length +
                " Face 1 Location X: " + faces[0].rect.centerX() +
                "Y: " + faces[0].rect.centerY() );
    }
}
}
```

`android.media.FaceDetector.face` **OR** `android.hardware.Camera.Face`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.media.FaceDetector.face`

I found a tutorial  on this too : [Implementing Face Detection in Android](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/10/28/implementing-face-detection-in-android)

Comment: If i do it. error is shown as : **Function must be declared as abstract or implement abstract method onFaceDetection(Face[]faces,Camera c)**